# PostGreSQL: outer join with a constant instead of a table

Tags: postgresql

Here is my problem, I have a query looking like:

```
INSERT INFO table (f1, f2, f3)
    SELECT t1.f1bis, t2.f2bis, t3.f3bis
    FROM   t1, t2, t3
    WHERE  t1.f1 = 'toto' AND
           t2.f2 = 'tata' AND
           t3.f3 ILIKE 'titi';
```

The problem is that if t3 doesn't contains 'titi', then the SELECT would return no lines at all.

What I would want is that when t3 doesn't contains TITI, the SELECT returns f3bis as NULL

I was thinking about the following query instead (forget about the INSERT):

```
SELECT t1.f1bis, t2.f2bis, t3.f3bis
FROM   t1, t2,
       ((SELECT 'titi' AS f3) AS dummytable)
           LEFT OUTER JOIN
       t3
           ON dummy_table.f3 = t3.f3
WHERE  t1.f1 = 'toto' AND
       t2.f2 = 'tata';
```

That would make sure that if 'titi' doesn't exist in t3, then I would get a NULL. But the query doesn't seem to work.

Can you help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Alternatives)

The effect of outer joins can also be obtained using correlated subqueries. For example

```
SELECT employee.LastName, employee.DepartmentID, department.DepartmentName 
FROM   employee LEFT OUTER JOIN department 
          ON employee.DepartmentID = department.DepartmentID
```

can also be written as

```
SELECT employee.LastName, employee.DepartmentID,
  (SELECT department.DepartmentName 
    FROM department
   WHERE employee.DepartmentID = department.DepartmentID ) AS DepartmentName
FROM   employee
```

So the answer to my question is the query:

```
SELECT t1.f1bis, t2.f2bis,
       (SELECT t3.f3bis
        FROM   t3
        WHERE  t3.f3 = 'titi'
       ) AS f3bis
FROM   t1, t2
WHERE  t1.f1 = 'toto' AND
       t2.f2 = 'tata';
```